# Recover old keychain after keychain reset

Tags: keychain, recovery

So, I did a keychain reset on a Mac due to some process taking up a lot of CPU (a keychain cloud daemon). This worked wonders for the cpu, but now the user wants its passwords back and doesn't care about a constantly running fan. 
Keychain manager told me that the old standard keychain will be set aside, but I have no experience with this and cannot for the life of me figure out how to restore the old one. Any ideas? I looked into ~/User/Libraries/Keychain but that gave me no further clues. I'm quite familiar with bash but totally blank on OSX so I appreciate a detailed explanation of the procedure.